# Is there a way to play The King of Fighters multiplayer on the PC?

Tags: pc, the-king-of-fighters

Many people say that they are the best in King of Fighters ver. 1.3. I also wondered if there is a player better than I am, but the only way to figure that out is by playing them in a multiplayer game.

I have heard of a new version where Mai and Chun Li would be released, but so far, I haven't found that game. So now I'm here wanting to know if any of you knew anything about a version of King of Fighters that allows multiplayer. Please tell me any information you may have.

Comment: I've edited the question to avoid it sounding like an off-topic question about future game releases or an off-topic recommendation question. This is to avoid getting the question closed.

Comment: @galacticninja I think they would've closed it three years ago if it had been off topic.

Comment: @ColeBusby Before my edit, this question got 2 close votes. [I made an edit to avoid further close votes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/49393).

Comment: @galacticninja Look at UnKnown's Posted Date. If they wanted to take it down I was saying they had time.

Comment: @ColeBusby I know. A question being years old does not make it immune from close votes, especially since policy changes over time. The close votes this question got before my edit were recent. See the [review queue](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/49393) link. They were made two days ago and currently haven't expired yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into playing older KoF games with an emulator that supports netplay ([see list](http://emulation-general.wikia.com/wiki/Netplay#Arcade)). There's also KoF XII, but it's not available on PC.

**Update:** As [Yotam Wilson mentions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131440/4302), KoF XIII is now available on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/222940/), so there’s finally an official way to play KoF online on PC. If an official release is what you were asking for, consider choosing his answer instead.

Comment: Note you need a Very low latency Internet Connection

Answer (score 4):

As of this September KOFXIII is available on steam with fairly improved netcode since the PS3 version

http://store.steampowered.com/app/222940/

Answer (score 0):

Today the best option is probably [MameHub](http://blog.mamehub.info/), also known as ClientServerMAME & ClientServerMESS.